# Why I'm getting different outputs for the following lines of code. (KDEplot visualisation)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, kernel-density

[image]

[image]

1.

```
Tot=sns.kdeplot(data=new_df_dummies, x=new_df_dummies.TotalCharges[new_df_dummies["Churn"]== 1], fill = True, color = 'blue')
```

2. 

```
Tot=sns.kdeplot(data=new_df_dummies, x=new_df_dummies.TotalCharges[new_df_dummies["Churn"]== 0], fill = True, color = 'red')
```

and 3.

```
Tot=sns.kdeplot(data=new_df_dummies, x=new_df_dummies.TotalCharges, hue="Churn", fill =True)
```

Shouldn't the lines 1 and 2 give the same output as line 3??

Comment: When you use `hue`, by default the curves are scaled down proportionally to their ratio in the dataset. You can change the default `common_norm=True` to `common_norm=False` if you don't want this. When the option `multiple='stack'` is set, the combined curve looks similar to the kde of the full dataset.